# MYSQL - Having trouble with query involving multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I need help writing a query to  find the name of students who are enrolled in a course taught by a professor who wrote an article called "X"

I have the code to find the professor who wrote the article, but I'm having trouble joining tables to find the names of students enrolled in a course taught by that prof.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, title)
FROM intellectual_contributions as ic, ic_contributors as icc, stakeholders as s
WHERE title ="X"
and ic.ic_id=icc.ic_id
and icc.stakeholder_id=s.stakeholder_id
```

Comment: Well, first of all you should learn the proper syntax. Your style of "joining" in the `WHERE` clause is deprecated since 1992. Here you can find examples and explanations of syntax and joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: ok, thanks for the link. I kind of realized that by looking at other questions. I'm not sure why my prof teaches us to join like this...

Answer (score 2):

You need some more `INNER JOIN`'s. Also, try to use `JOIN`ed syntax.

```
SELECT aa.first_name, aa.last_name, cc.title
FROM stakeholders AS aa
INNER JOIN ic_contributors AS bb
ON aa.stakeholder_id = bb.stakeholder_id
INNER JOIN intellectual_contributions AS cc
ON bb.ic_id = cc.ic_id
INNER JOIN course_enrollments AS dd
ON aa.stakeholder_id = dd.stakeholder_id
WHERE cc.title = "X";
```

Comment: The query only got me the professor who wrote the article, but not students enrolled in  a course he's instructing

Comment: Try the above and please let me know if this is what you want.